# WHat is the best method to fetch social media data?

Tags: apache-spark

Hey I am a new guy to big data. I am making a system which will fetch data from social media and process the result, for this I am using apache spark.

Following is the flow of my model:

1. user will save the desired keywords using a webpage made in php.
2. with those key words I would be fetching data from social media,
       processing the data(ex, sentiments and views) and then provide it to
       the end user.

Now my confusion is how should I fetch data from social media. using

- apache kafka
- apache flume
- or by directly calling the API twitter4j(just an example).

Though I have to learn to implement all three data fetching techniques, and If I happen to use direct api then I can skip the whole hadoop part. It would be great if you guys could suggest me which one is better.

All of the above I am doing on a local machine. I have completed the ui part now I am in the phase where I have to fetch data.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I will make this a suggestion.

You may not want to fetch data from any source using distributed system, unless you plan to DDoS their production server. If your cluster is setup behind one router, your whole cluster may be blacklisted because all nodes consistently hit the access rate limit that's adding up at your router, depending on whether the server is powerful or not. Twitter server doesn't care about 100 threads to be honest (provided you know what you are doing), but any startup will probably get to you right away.

If you have a workstation with 4 cores, having it up catching streaming data should suffice for initial stage of academic research. Or if you really want tons of data, you can perhaps do Hadoop streaming with your fetcher script as mapper and no reducer, quick and easy. If you are superstar in Java or Scala, get a fetching thread on each vcore on Spark's executor.

Now, Twitter has the REST API, which means you can pretty much fetch data in any programming language. Of course sometimes it may be easier to use existing interfaces, assuming they are well-maintained, they are almost always more robust. But I get lazy all the time. For example, I sometimes just want a sample data point, so I just pipe `curl` into `jq` to check what I want to check.

Yes, learn about `jq` too, will save you tons of time. And be a gentleman who doesn't DDoS people.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am making it as a project for demo purpose so even records in 100s will do for me and yes I do know scala. That is why I am confused which would be the better way. Using rest APIs or using kafka or flume, and yes I am well aware about the rate limits. So my plan is to get some data for testing and when it works fine then get some more data for demo.

Comment: @UmeshKaushik I think you are still confused, so I will make it crystal and please do not take it offensive. Once you hit the rate limit it doesn't matter how many threads you have in however many container/executor. For most purposes, unless you have an agreement with Twitter, any distributed system (Hadoop / Spark) is very over-killing.

Comment: @UmeshKaushik Say you have 10 executors with 4 cores each on Spark, then you would be running 40 threads. But that will hit the same rate limit that the 4-thread `Python` script hits in a single-node process. So why `Big-Data` when `small data` is enough.

Comment: @UmeshKaushik If you use Spark to crawl or fetch data from all kinds of sources, any organization that are not intelligent enough to set rate limit will have their production server bombed down by you. Your supervisor may then get an angry email, because his desktop has the same ip prefix as yours.